# jquery event not working for dynamic elements

Tags: jquery

on click of button i am adding dynamic element eg: anchor tag having some id,
on clicking the dynamic element alert should open which is not happening.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").on("click",function(){
         $("#op").html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='demo'>Click</a>");
    });
    $("#demo").on("click",function(){
        alert('In Demo....');
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<pre id='op' ></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on("click","#submit",function(){
     $("#op").html("<a href='javascript:void(0)' id='demo'>Click</a>");
});

$(document).on("click","#demo",function(){
    alert('In Demo....');
});
```

The problem is that your events are not attached to the element.

Comment: Awesome @Kinshuk Lahiri

Comment: @KinshukLahiri, what about if you want to add multiple, you are using id there  id='demo'

Comment: @EaBangalore then instead of that you should use class and use `this` instead. @Raman No worries, take your time and learn. Happy programming.